# How to change \\ into \

Tags: java, backslash

I just made a small program that saves a path into an INI file.

But on the output, the path is written like so :

```
C:\\Windows
```

I want it to be put like so :

```
C:\Windows
```

I tried many way with the string.replace but one backslash gives error and putting 4 doesn't makes 1 backslashes in the output but 4...

I am out of ideas.

Comment: Why do you need to write using \ ? This file will be read by some Windows (native) application?

Comment: If the INI file is a Properties file, you don't have the choice: you are stuck with the predefined rules for properties files, which dictate backslashes as escape characters, and therefore double backslashes to represent epreal backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [File Separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) will give you the platform independent character and you wont have to escape it.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075373/file-separator-vs-filesystem-getseparator-vs-system-getpropertiesfile-separa) question for all the different options.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to get the double backslash:

```
System.out.println("File path = C:\\"+"\\"+"Windows");
```

Would output this:

```
C:\\Windows
```

Answer (score 1):

As the OP is using Java and I'm assuming that this INI file will be used by a Java application, I don't think that he needs to write the path using backslashes, since Java will convert normal slashes to backslashes in Windows using the File Separator under the hood. So, just write `C:/Windows` or `C:/some/path/here` and it will work normally.