# File handling in java with permission denied and wrong path

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception, permission-denied

i have a java class which reads and gives me the list of files available for the particular given path.

this is fine when the right path is given but there is no exception or error if the file path is not accessible or wrong path,

how to handle the following,

1. Given path does not have a permission to access
2. wrong path is given.

thanks

This is my code what i tried and it is the `jdk version is 1.6`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExceptionInFileHandling {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void GetDirectory(String a_Path, List a_files, List a_folders) throws IOException {
        try {
            File l_Directory = new File(a_Path);
            File[] l_files = l_Directory.listFiles();

            for (int c = 0; c < l_files.length; c++) {
                if (l_files[c].isDirectory()) {
                    a_folders.add(l_files[c].getName());
                } else {
                        a_files.add(l_files[c].getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        String filesLocation = "asdfasdf/sdfsdf/";
        List l_Files = new ArrayList(), l_Folders = new ArrayList();
        GetDirectory(filesLocation, l_Files, l_Folders);

        System.out.println("Files");
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        for (Object file : l_Files) {
            System.out.println(file);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");

    }
}
```

Comment: *sigh* where's your code so far?

Comment: @Smutje hope you will be able to answer now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
To replace the file separator based on the OS, answers for similar thread

[Java regex to replace file path based on OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039645/java-regex-to-replace-file-path-based-on-os)

[Platform independent paths in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java)

**Solution 2:**
To check wrong path, you may use below code.

```
  @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        public static void GetDirectory(String a_Path, List a_files, List a_folders) throws IOException {
            try {
                if (!new File(a_Path).exists())
                {
                   throw new FileNotFoundException("Given path '"+a_Path+"' is not available");
                }
                File l_Directory = new File(a_Path);
                File[] l_files = l_Directory.listFiles();

                for (int c = 0; c < l_files.length; c++) {
                    if (l_files[c].isDirectory()) {
                        a_folders.add(l_files[c].getName());
                    } else {
                            a_files.add(l_files[c].getName());
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }            
        }
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use so e methods of `File` class.
`Exists` will tell you if the path given is valid and `canRead` will determine if you have read permision to particular file/directory.
Here you have some [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public static void GetDirectory(String a_Path, List a_files, List a_folders) throws IOException {
        try {
            File l_Directory = new File(a_Path);
            **if(l_Directory.exists()){**
                File[] l_files = l_Directory.listFiles();

                for (int c = 0; c < l_files.length; c++) {
                    if (l_files[c].isDirectory()) {
                        a_folders.add(l_files[c].getName());
                    } else {
                            a_files.add(l_files[c].getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: one more question @sunysen, givenPath.replaceAll("\\\\|/", "\\"+System.getProperty("file.separator")); is this will replace the file separator based on the OS or only for windows

Comment: I give file path as argument and that loading file should not be dependent on any OS

Comment: NO NO, the String filesLocation = "asdfasdf/sdfsdf/"; should not be dependant on any OS

Comment: ExceptionInFileHandling .class.getClassLoader().getResource("asdfasdf/sdfsdf/").getPath(),Do not ?

Comment: i get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65125/discussion-between-anto-and-sunysen).