# how to change the file path based on the OS

Tags: java, linux, windows, file

i have a class which reads the list available in particular location,

the following is my code,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExceptionInFileHandling {

   @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
   public static void GetDirectory(String a_Path, List a_files, List a_folders) throws IOException {
       try {
           File l_Directory = new File(a_Path);
           File[] l_files = l_Directory.listFiles();

           for (int c = 0; c < l_files.length; c++) {
               if (l_files[c].isDirectory()) {
                   a_folders.add(l_files[c].getName());
               } else {
                   a_files.add(l_files[c].getName());
               }
           }
       } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }

   }
   @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

       String filesLocation = "asdfasdf/sdfsdf/";
       List l_Files = new ArrayList(), l_Folders = new ArrayList();
       GetDirectory(filesLocation, l_Files, l_Folders);

       System.out.println("Files");
       System.out.println("---------------------------");
       for (Object file : l_Files) {
           System.out.println(file);
       }
       System.out.println("Done");

   }
}
```

in this the file path can be passed as argument and that should be taken up based on the OS,

```
filePath.replaceAll("\\\\|/", "\\" + System.getProperty("file.separator"))
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 8):

### There are better ways to use file paths...

```
// Don't do this
filePath.replaceAll("\\\\|/", "\\" + System.getProperty("file.separator"))
```

#### Use [java.nio.file.path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html):

```
import java.nio.file.*;
```

---

```
Path path = Paths.get(somePathString);
// Here is your system independent path
path.toAbsolutePath();
// Or this works too
Paths.get(somePathString).toAbsolutePath();
```

#### Use [File.seperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

```
// You can also input a String that has a proper file seperator like so
String filePath = "SomeDirectory" + File.separator;
// Then call your directory method
try{
    ExceptionInFileHandling.GetDirectory(filePath, ..., ...);
} catch (Exception e){}
```

---

#### So a simple change to your method will now work cross platform:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
   public static void GetDirectory(String a_Path, List a_files, List a_folders) throws IOException {
       try {
           // File object is instead constructed 
           // with a URI by using Path.toUri()
           // Change is done here
           File l_Directory = new File(Paths.get(a_Path).toUri());

           File[] l_files = l_Directory.listFiles();
           for (int c = 0; c < l_files.length; c++) {
               if (l_files[c].isDirectory()) {
                   a_folders.add(l_files[c].getName());
               } else {
                   a_files.add(l_files[c].getName());
               }
           }
       } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use forward slashes as directory separators on Windows as well when calling File constructor.

Comment: i am sorry and dont really get you, please add some examples

Comment: @JavaQuestions you just need no modifications to your code. The path `asdfasdf/sdfsdf/` will be regarded as directory `sdfsdf` inside directory `asdfasdf` inside current directory. On any platform. You should not replace `/` for backslash on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

why you are not adding java defined file separator instead of creating a string then replacing all.
try it like

```
String filesLocation = "asdfasdf"+File.separator+"sdfsdf"+File.separator;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from you should be correct. There is another similiar thread with answer :

[Java regex to replace file path based on OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039645/java-regex-to-replace-file-path-based-on-os)

[Platform independent paths in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548775/platform-independent-paths-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not used relative path like `asdfasdf/sdfsdf/`. It's a big source of bugs as your path depends on your working directory.

That thing said, your replaceAll is quite good but it can be improved like this :

```
filePath.replaceAll(
    "[/\\\\]+",
    Matcher.quoteReplacement(System.getProperty("file.separator")));
```

Using [`quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29) is adviced in [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) documentation

> Returns a literal replacement String for the specified String. This method produces a String that will work as a literal replacement s in the appendReplacement method of the Matcher class. The String produced will match the sequence of characters in s treated as a literal sequence. Slashes ('\') and dollar signs ('$') will be given no special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a `Path` object from the passed argument. Then you would not need to handle the file separator on your own.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path path = Paths.get(args[0]);
    System.out.println("path = " + path.toAbsolutePath());
}
```

The code is able to handle following passed arguments.

- foo\bar
- foo/bar
- foo\bar/baz
- foo\\bar
- foo//baz
- foo\\bar//baz
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `java.io.File.separatorChar` to The system-dependent default name-separator character.

String location = "usr"+java.io.File.separatorChar+"local"+java.io.File.separatorChar;

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils contains a lot of useful methods, for instance separatorsToSystem(String path) converts separators in given path in accordance with OS which you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method to know about OS file separator and then replaceAll previous separator with this methods.

```
System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you just dont use "/". It is acceptable for both linux and windows as path seperator.