# Remove filename from a URL/Path in java

Tags: java, string, filepath, platform-independent

How do I remove the file name from a URL or String?

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        String nativeDir = Game.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile().toString();

        //Remove the <name>.jar from the string
        if(nativeDir.endsWith(".jar"))
            nativeDir = nativeDir.substring(0, nativeDir.lastIndexOf("/"));

        //Load the right native files
        for(File f : (new File(nativeDir + File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "native")).listFiles()){
            if(f.isDirectory() && os.contains(f.getName().toLowerCase())){
                System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", f.getAbsolutePath()); break;
            }
        }
```

That's what I have right now, and it work. From what I know, because I use "/" it will only work for windows. I want to make it platform independent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075373/file-separator-vs-filesystem-getseparator-vs-system-getpropertiesfile-separa

Comment: This `/` is not windows. ` \ ` is!

Answer (score 26):

Consider using [org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html)

You can extract the base path, file name, extensions etc with any flavor of file separator:

```
String url = "C:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe";

String baseUrl = FilenameUtils.getPath(url);
String myFile = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(url)
                + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(url);

System.out.println(baseUrl);
System.out.println(myFile);
```

Gives,

```
windows\system32\
cmd.exe
```

With url; `String url = "C:/windows/system32/cmd.exe";`

It would give;

```
windows/system32/
cmd.exe
```

Comment: I don't have `FilenameUtils` I can't import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.

Comment: @yemto can't import would be "not supposed to" or "don't know what lib has it"?

Comment: @PopoFido oh, I don't like to use library's, especially for something that should be this simple.

Comment: What about the drive letter?

Answer (score 23):

By utilizing **java.nio.file**; (afaik introduced after J2SE 1.7) this simply solved my problem:

```
Path path = Paths.get(fileNameWithFullPath);
String directory = path.getParent().toString();
```

Comment: Doesn't work well for HTTP URLs, which wasn't specifically mentioned in the question, but might be of interest to some browsing these answers.

Answer (score 15):

You are using File.separator in another line. Why not using it also for your lastIndexOf()?

```
nativeDir = nativeDir.substring(0, nativeDir.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
```

Comment: Because It returns the wrong thing for my system. But it don't seam to care if it becomes C:\something\something\something/something

Comment: The File.separator is returning the file separator dependent to your system. So on Windows you will get "\" while on Unix you get "/". That's why you should use the File.separator.

Comment: `Game.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile().toString()` returns **D:/Dropbox/NetBeansProjects/** while `System.out.println(File.separator)` returns \ so that's wrong. I have windows 7 64bit

Comment: Well if that method always returns "/" you might want to perform a replacement first to ensure the same state in any case. String.replace() might help

Comment: Notice that in order to get the **filename**, expression should be something like `nativeDir.substring(nativeDir.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1)` (so the substring *from* the separator, *to* the end).

Answer (score 9):

```
File file = new File(path);
String pathWithoutFileName = file.getParent();
```

where **path** could be "C:\Users\userName\Desktop\file.txt"

Comment: This should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 3):

The standard library can handle this as of Java 7

```
Path pathOnly;

if (file.getNameCount() > 0) {
  pathOnly = file.subpath(0, file.getNameCount() - 1);
} else {
  pathOnly = file;
}

fileFunction.accept(pathOnly, file.getFileName());
```

Comment: path.getNameCount() documentation says: "the number of elements in the path, or 0 if this path only represents a root component" This could cause issues...

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin solution:

```
val file = File( "/folder1/folder2/folder3/readme.txt")
val pathOnly = file.absolutePath.substringBeforeLast( File.separator )
println( pathOnly )
```

produces this result:

/folder1/folder2/folder3

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "/", use [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator). It is either `/` or `\`, depending on the platform. If this is not solving your issue, then use [`FileSystem.getSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getSeparator%28%29): you can pass different filesystems, instead of the default.

Comment: I would. But File.separator return a "\" while nativeDir uses "/"

Comment: Then shouldn't something like this work?

`if(nativeDir.endsWith(".jar")){
            int index = Math.max(nativeDir.lastIndexOf("/"), nativeDir.lastIndexOf("\\"));
            nativeDir = nativeDir.substring(0, index);
        }`

Comment: Added more info. That should resolve the difference with native dir.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using regex.

For windows:

```
String path = "";
String filename = "d:\\folder1\\subfolder11\\file.ext";
String regEx4Win = "\\\\(?=[^\\\\]+$)";
String[] tokens = filename.split(regEx4Win);
if (tokens.length > 0)
   path = tokens[0]; // path -> d:\folder1\subfolder11
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code:

```
file.getPath().replace(file.getName(), "");
```

Comment: Breaks if any directory has the same name as the target file. Since files without an extension are fine from an OS point of view, this may lead to something like: `C:\A\B\C\B` being changed to `C:\A\\C`, so you have unintentionally lost a directory.